# Calculate vehicle velocity from NMEA sentences

Tags: gps, nmea

I wanted to get the position(latitude and longitude) and velocity of my vehicle by using SIM908 GPS/GPRS module. The module will be kept in my vehicle.

I'm able to get the position(latitude and longitude) of my vehicle from the NMEA sentences, but for the velocity, I'm not so sure about it.

I found that in the NMEA sentence, there is a $GPVTG which contains the "speed over ground in km/h".

My question is, does the "speed over ground in km/h" means my vehicle velocity on the road? Or I need to do some calculations from it to get the actual velocity of my vehicle?

If the "speed over ground in km/h" doesn't mean my vehicle velocity on the road, then what can I do to get my vehicle's velocity?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of vehicle do you have?
In a car, speed ofer ground is the speed on the road.
In a ship, speed over ground can differ from the speed through water (as the water can have currents). Same in the air.

The GPS can only know the speed over ground, as is is the real physical movement that the satellite receiver measures. It does not now about currents.

Typically this is already the value that you need. For water/air speed you need a special measuring device like a log.